# How to Read PDF File using PHP

Tags: php, class, pdf

Can we read PDF using PHP?
I want to read single page pdf file by php. If yes please give me some example. Single class file is more appropriate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "read"?

Comment: grab plain text from the pdf file

Comment: On what platform? Does your platform have `strings`?

Comment: or convert pdf to HML

Comment: Most PDF(s) don't contain "plain" text.

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of techniques to read PDF using PHP. I won't be using the code in here because it is not appropriate on the premise that we don't know what is your exact use case. But here are a few links that could help you out. In no particular order,

- FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/
- FPDF is a PDF reader for PHP. The one below, is more like a converter.
- PDF TO HTML http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/
- Free PDF Document Importer: http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/

Comment: Edited that with your mention @ElliottFrisch