# How to read a PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I have a feature that updates product information by reading a CSV file. These CSV files are given to me by various different external sources, and I cannot control what format they are given to me in. 
One of these sources gives me the information in PDF format (God knows why) and at the moment I am having to update the information manually, which is very time consuming.

I need to add onto this feature, so either a PDF or a CSV can be uploaded.

I have looked at previously asked questions on SO ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834458/how-to-read-pdf-file-using-php)), but the examples shown are more catered towards editing a PDF, rather than just reading the file and storing it in a variable.

My question is, how can I read the contents of a PDF file with PHP and store it in a variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can help you out but it's a bit of a lenghty process. Is there a way to contact you?

Comment: Are you searching an open source/free solution or will be a commercial product work for you too?

Comment: @Setasign I am looking for an open source/free solution

Comment: So if you can go with the GPL you may check [this](http://pdfparser.org/) out.